# SQL: Getting the period start and end datetimes from data like this? Tricky little puzzle I'm struggling with

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, group-by

I have a table which lists every date within the year. Each row also contains a period number from 1 to 13 which loop around each year.
It looks something like this:

```
|        Date         | Period |
| 2012-12-27 00:00:00 |   12   |
| 2012-12-28 00:00:00 |   12   |
| 2012-12-29 00:00:00 |   13   |
| 2012-12-30 00:00:00 |   13   |
| 2012-12-31 00:00:00 |   13   |
| 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |   13   |
| 2013-01-02 00:00:00 |   13   |
|        . . .        |   13   | 
| 2013-02-10 00:00:00 |   01   |
|        . . .        |   01   | 
| 2013-03-14 00:00:00 |   02   |
|        . . .        |   02   | 
| 2013-05-05 00:00:00 |   03   |
```

As you can see above, period 13 starts on the 29th of dec 2012 and finishes on the 09th of Febuary 2013.
I work this out by getting the first and last dates for period 13.

**I need to write a query that will get the period start and end dates for the current period.
But I'm having problems because the periods sometimes occur twice a year and sometimes overlap between the years like this example does.**

A few more examples:

If getDate() = '2013-02-25 13:45:00' then the period should be 01 and the start and end dates would be '2013-02-10 00:00:00' and '2013-03-14 00:00:00'

If getDate() = '2013-03-15 00:00:00' then the period should be 02 and the start and end dates would be '2013-03-14 00:00:00' and '2013-05-05 00:00:00'

I really hope this makes sense. Let me know if I need to clarify it! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do all consecutive dates exist in the table (no gaps) and one row per date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using SQL Server 2012, you would use `lag` or `lead` for this.  Instead, I'm going to use a correlated subquery:

```
select min(period) as period, MIN(date), MAX(date)
from (select t.*,
             (select min(date) from t t2 where t2.period <> t.period and t2.date > t.date) as nextp
      from t
     ) t
group by nextp
```

The inner subquery gets the date of the *next* period.  This is the same for consecutive records with the same period record.  I can then use this for grouping.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick reply Gordon. This query is close to what I want but its unfortunately returning the wrong dates.

Each year there is 13 periods and in my table I have records from 2005 onwards. Because its getting the min and max(date) it is return records from way back then rather than for the current period. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1636130 . . . Stupid me.  The defined `nextp` and then grouped by `period`.  I fixed the problem.  It should now work as I described it.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I got this to work in the end. I am very pleased with it

Answer (score 3):

Two recursive cte's that finds the start date and end date in a period.

```
with CStart as
(
  select Date,
         Period
  from DateTable
  where Date = cast(getdate() as date)
  union all
  select D.Date,
         D.Period
  from DateTable as D
    inner join CStart
      on dateadd(day, -1, CStart.Date) = D.Date and
         CStart.Period = D.Period
),
CEnd as
(
  select Date,
         Period
  from DateTable
  where Date = cast(getdate() as date)
  union all
  select D.Date,
         D.Period
  from DateTable as D
    inner join CEnd
      on dateadd(day, 1, CEnd.Date) = D.Date and
         CEnd.Period = D.Period
),
CPeriod as
(
  select Period
  from DateTable
  where Date = cast(getdate() as date)
)
select Period,
       (select min(Date) from CStart) as StartDate,
       (select max(Date) from CEnd) as EndDate 
from CPeriod
```

Test on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90883)

Answer (score 1):

Give this code a try

```
DECLARE @TODAYSPERIOD AS VARCHAR(2)

SET @TODAYSPERIOD = (SELECT PERIOD FROM MYTABLE
                    WHERE DATE = (DATEADD(D, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))

SELECT MAX(DATE), MIN(DATE), @TODAYSPERIOD FROM MYTABLE
WHERE PERIOD = @TODAYSPERIOD AND DATE BETWEEN ((DATEADD(D, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) - 45) AND ((DATEADD(D, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) + 45)
```

Essentially, we're using your table (in the above code, it is referenced to as 'MYTABLE') to find the period and then taking only dates within a 45 day radius (both before and after the current date) that is listed as the same period as today.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try (in my test data, 56 was the largest number of days in a given period)

```
SELECT A.period
     , MIN( B.date )
     , MAX( B.date )
  FROM dates A
 INNER JOIN dates B
    ON A.date >= DATEADD( dd, -56, B.date )
   AND A.date <= DATEADD( dd, 56, B.date )
   AND A.period = B.period 
 GROUP BY A.period
```

Answer (score 0):

**If - and only if** - no date gaps exist in the table and there is exactly one row per date, you can use this:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT
        a.Date AS StartDate
      , b.Date AS EndDate
      , a.Period
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Date) AS rn
    FROM tableX AS a
      LEFT JOIN tableX AS b
        ON  DATEADD(day, -1, a.Date) = b.Date
    WHERE a.Period <> b.Period 
       OR b.Date IS NULL 
  )
SELECT
    a.StartDate
  , COALESCE(b.EndDate, (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM tableX)) AS EndDate
  , a.Period
FROM
    cte AS a
  LEFT JOIN 
    cte AS b
      ON a.rn + 1 = b.rn ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56806/3)**